# lag over columns/ variables SPSS

Tags: loops, vector, repeat, spss, lag

I want to do something I thought was really simple.
My (mock) data looks like this:

[image]

```
data list free/totalscore.1 to totalscore.5.
begin data.
1 2 6 7 10 1 4 9 11 12 0 2 4 6 9   
end data.
```

These are total scores accumulating over a number of trials (in this mock data, from 1 to 5). Now I want to know the number of scores earned in each trial. In other words, I want to subtract the value in the n trial from the n+1 trial. 
The most simple syntax would look like this:

```
COMPUTE trialscore.1 = totalscore.2 - totalscore.1.
EXECUTE. 

COMPUTE trialscore.2 = totalscore.3 - totalscore.2.
EXECUTE. 

COMPUTE trialscore.3 = totalscore.4 - totalscore.3.
EXECUTE.
```

And so on... 
So that the result would look like this:

[image]

But of course it is not possible and not fun to do this for 200+ variables. 
I attempted to write a syntax using VECTOR and DO REPEAT as follows:

```
COMPUTE #y = 1.
VECTOR totalscore = totalscore.1 to totalscore.5. 
DO REPEAT trialscore = trialscore.1 to trialscore.5.
COMPUTE #y = #x + 1. 
END REPEAT. 
COMPUTE trialscore(#i) = totalscore(#y) - totalscore(#i). 
EXECUTE.
```

But it doesn't work. 
Any help is appreciated.

Ps. I've looked into using LAG but that loops over rows while I need it to go over 1 column at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming `respid` is your original (unique) record identifier.

**EDIT:**

If you do not have a record indentifier, you can very easily create a dummy one:

```
compute respid=$casenum.
exe.
```

**end of EDIT**

You could try re-structuring the data, so that each score is a distinct record:

```
varstocases
/make totalscore from totalscore.1 to totalscore.5
/index=scorenumber
/NULL=keep.
exe.
```

then sort your cases so that scores are in descending order (in order to be bale to use `lag` function):

```
sort cases by respid (a) scorenumber (d).
```

Then actually do the `lag`-based computations

```
do if respid=lag(respid).
    compute trialscore=totalscore-lag(totalscore).
end if.
exe.
```

In the end, un-do the restructuring:

```
casestovars
/id=respid
/index=scorenumber.
exe.
```

You should end up with a set of `totalscore` variables (the last one will be empty), which will hold what you need.

Comment: Hi horace_vr, thank you very  much for your help. 
I think I need to swap "trialscore" with "totalscore" in order for the code to work.
So basically, your suggestion is to transpose the data and then still use lag. Is there any other solution? I'm really curious how index/subscript works in SPSS syntax. 
Also, what should I do if I dont have a unique record identifier?

Comment: @TVV : you are correct about swapping; I edited the code so swapping is not needed anymore. I also added a line on how to create a record identifier. I don't know how to else solve it; if you use vectors, due to the need to always "look" for data in the previous variable, you'll always get some warnings, which I do not think is a smart way to work (you'll end up ignoring the warning, and at some point you might also end up an eventual error ;)). You could also try Python, but I think that would over-complicate things.My code is quite short and you only need to edit in 1 single place ;)

Comment: @TVV : you are correct about swapping; I edited the code so swapping is not needed anymore. I also added a line on how to create a record identifier. I don't know how to else solve it; if you use vectors, due to the need to always "look" for data in the previous variable, you'll always get some warnings, which I do not think is a smart way to work (you'll end up ignoring the warning, and at some point you might also end up an eventual error ;)). You could also try Python, but I think that would over-complicate things.My code is quite short and you only need to edit in 1 single place ;)

Comment: Hi horace_vr, it worked! Thanks a lot! Yes I do realize that it is much simpler to do this in Python or in R, but at the moment I am sort of stuck with SPSS. Thanks a lot for your help! Btw, it only worked when I did not sort cases by respid.

Comment: Are you sure about not sorting by respid...? It is crucial to have the data sorted, otherwise the lag does not do its job

Answer (score 1):

you can use `do repeat` this way:

```
do repeat 
   before=totalscore.1 to totalscore.4
  /after=totalscore.2 to totalscore.5
  /diff=trialscore.1 to trialscore.4 . 
compute diff=after-before.
end repeat.
```